# How to get error messages for org-preview-latex-fragment?

Tags: org-mode, latex

*(This took a long time to research, so I'm answering my own question, hoping to save others some time)*

Let's say I have a file like this:

```
one by two is $\froc1{2}$
```

When I run `M-x org-preview-latex-fragment`, all I get is a white square indicating that something went wrong and in the *Messages* buffer the line:

> Cannot find image file ‘/home/.../ltxpng/....png’

How can I view the error message?

Comment: If you replace the Orgmode LaTeX fragment system by [`texfrag`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) you get a menu item sending you to the error message buffer and one that is sending you to the LaTeX log file.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291339/3014199
look for a file in `/tmp` something like `/tmp/orgtex*.log`.
That works on my linux machine at least.